# Fatal error get for product upload in magento

Tags: magento

Now I uploaded an image for my new product in my magento store. But I got an error like this.

**Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1860 bytes) in /home/weraemer/public_html/theme_name/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 88** .

Can any one give the suggestion to solve this error.

Thanks

Comment: Please increase the memory limit it might work

Answer (score 0):

you can increase the memory limit in php.ini file in your magento folder